# Constant Value for Every Row From DataBase Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I want to retrieve data (number of rows) from a DB in my Laravel project.
Some of them should have `Live Event` as their `status` field and others should have `Past Event` as their `status` field.

How can I do that is Laravel Query Builder?

Example:

```
EventName    status
 a          'Live Event'
 b          'Live Event'
 c          'Past Event'
 d          'LiveEvent'
 e          'Past Event'
```

Comment: You haven't stated how the status should be resolved. But take a look at [case syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) in mysql, if it's resolved based on another field.

Answer (score 2):

Found an Answer..

```
$LatestpastEventsDetails = DB::table('event')->select('eventName', DB::raw('"live" as status'))->get();
```

do the same for live and , upcomming..
use Union to retrieve the full dataset